# iAds are not showing in Swift 2, Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, swift, iad

I've read bunch of tutorials, watched many videos, read some articles about iAds and every one of them says you should get this:

[image: iAds picture]

.. if you managed to connect your app to iAd. I've got that when I've run my app, but yesterday my app has gone live on App Store and ads are not showing.

I imported iAds in my ViewController with `import iAd`, used `ADBannerViewDelegate` and implemented:

```
func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
        NSLog("Error loading iAds: \(error)")
        iadBanner.hidden = true
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
        iadBanner.hidden = false
}
```

And in viewDidLoad():

```
iadBanner.delegate = self
```

I made an autlet: `@IBOutlet weak var iadBanner: ADBannerView!`

Affter all of that, ads somehow fail to show. Can somebody enlighten me about this?

Comment: what country have you released in, does it have ads?

Comment: I don't understand the question, can you elaborate?

Comment: What is the status of your app in the iAd workbench available from iTunesConnect?

Comment: I don't have anything there, just Apple promo for advertising

Comment: which app stores is the app available in, which countries?

Comment: Every App Store there is.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Apple is discontinuing iAd June 30th, 2016, and is not currently accepting new apps into their iAd network anymore.

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01152016a

If this is an older app from before their iAd discontinued period came into effect, it can usually take up to a few days for ads to become active. I would give it more time. If you tested this and saw the test banner, I believe you will see ads. I wouldn't rely on your own release version testing to see it, but rather the reports in iTunes Connect.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense but I saw on some tutorials that you have to get a contract for iAds in your Taxes... section. I don't have that option. I have a bad feeling that maybe, because of my location, I can't use iAds at all.

Comment: In your iTunes account, under "Agreements, Tax, Banking", do you have any outstanding contracts? Particularly iAd App Network Contract Type? This should all be squared away and taken care of before going live with release. I don't have much advice if it's not, other than get it done ASAP.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. There is no iAd App Network Contract. Just Paid apps contract

Comment: You are **not** able to get an iAd contract anymore.